# Populating the Shield UI ASP.NET chart with data on page load

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I am using s Shield UI ASP.NET chart  to build up a web page. I put a shield ui control and on the TakeDataSource event I put the following code:

```
    protected void ShieldChart1_TakeDataSource(object sender, Shield.Web.UI.ChartTakeDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        ShieldChart1.DataSource = new object[] 
        {
            new { visits = 312000 }, 
            new { visits = 12000 }, 
            new { visits = 121000 }, 
            new { visits = 232000 }, 
            new { visits = 145000 }, 
            new { visits = 147000 }
        };
    }
```

In debug mode the code is being executed, however there is no data on the chart at all. 
And this is my code from the HTML part of the page:

```
            <shield:ShieldChart ID="ShieldChart1" runat="server" Width="320px" Height="330px"
                OnTakeDataSource="ShieldChart1_TakeDataSource">
            </shield:ShieldChart>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I believe you have to define Axies and DataSeries as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one more thing that you need in your brief  code sample. 
First you need to specify the type of the data series you are going to use. And more important- you need to bind that data series to the data, already made available in the  ShieldChart1_TakeDataSource event:

```
<DataSeries>
    <shield:ChartBarSeries DataFieldY="visits">
    </shield:ChartBarSeries>
</DataSeries>
```

The DataFieldY="visits" property specifies that values on the Y axis will be taken from the assigned variable.